# BigQuery Export table for some tables causes quotaExceeded error on Web UI console

Tags: google-bigquery

Executing "Export table" for a certain table on BigQuery WebUI has the following error:

```
Error Reason:quotaExceeded. Get more information about this error at Troubleshooting Errors: quotaExceeded.
Errors:
extract_job.long, Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for exports. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors
Job ID: dataset-name:job_Ot7GnH4UUnq5ZHSY00gXJiOCZFs
Start Time: Sep 14, 2015, 4:55:29 PM
End Time: Sep 14, 2015, 4:55:29 PM
Source Table: project-id:dataset-name.table-name
Destination URI: gs://bucket/target.json
```

I encountered the same quotaExceeded (403) error more than 10 times with 100% failure rate.

I can't get the reason why I failed to export the table.

1. The following API Quota looks below the quota: https://console.developers.google.com/project/:project-id/apiui/apiview/bigquery/usage?duration=P1D
2. Quota summary shown on https://console.developers.google.com/project/:project-id/apiui/apiview/bigquery/quotas is as follows:

   ```
   Quota summary

   Daily quota resets at midnight Pacific Time (PT).

   Free quota  10,000 requests/day
   Total quota 200,000 requests/day
   Remaining   200,000 requests/day
               100% of total
   Per-user limit  100 requests/second/user
   ```
3. The project is billing enabled.
4. The table to be exported has 1,093,866 rows and 235,256,656 bytes.
5. The destinationUris property is specified as Single URI.

Any missing part for get succeeded in this export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotas in question are defined here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#export_jobs

Unfortunately, there is no console for viewing your quota status right now. The consoles you're looking at are for BigQuery API calls made an app running that project. They do not cover quotas for BigQuery jobs that are run in that project.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy.

While I've checked the quota definition you mentioned, I don't think I reached any of the quotas:

    Multiple Wildcard URI Limit: 500 URIs per export

I just specified a single URI for cloud storage at that time.

    Daily Limit: 1,000 exports per day, up to 10 TB

I don't think they reached this daily limit. How can we get the usage against this daily limit?

Comment: Next time you hit the limit, send your project ID to jcondit@google.com and I'll check your quota status.